# Issues with invoking firebase function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling with calling a firebase function from a web app-mobile application running on react/ionic.

The case is that I have a car diary application and for a particular vehicle I have sub-collections with refuels/repairs and so on. When a user wants to remove a vehicle I want to remove also its sub-collections, but as we all know there is no built-in function for this. As I understand the proper way to achieve this is to create a firebase function. And here the problem comes... this is my first collision with them and now I am racing for 3 days onto this.

This is the function/index.js:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const cleanupAfterVehicle = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 }).https.onRequest(async 
(request, response) => {
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');

const userId = request.body.userId;
const vehicleId = request.body.vehicleId;

const collectionPath = `users/${userId}/vehicles/${vehicleId}/repairs`;
const token = 'MY TOKEN';

await firebase_tools.delete(collectionPath, {
    project: 'project',
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
    token: token,
    });
});
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "functions",
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
"shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"engines": {
"node": "10"
},
"main": "lib/index.js",
"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
"firebase-tools": "^7.16.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"typescript": "^3.8.0",
"firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

In the application service I am trying to invoke it:

```
private async cleanupAfterVehicleRemove(vehicleId: string): Promise<void> {
    let cleanupAfterVehicleFunction = functions.httpsCallable('cleanupAfterVehicle');
    
    await cleanupAfterVehicleFunction({ userId: window.authContext.userId, vehicleId: vehicleId 
}).then((result) => console.log(result));
}
```

The first problem from the firebase logs:

```
TypeError: firebase_tools.delete is not a function
at exports.cleanupAfterVehicle.functions.runWith.https.onRequest (/workspace/lib/index.js:13:32)
at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:51:16)
at process.nextTick (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:99:17)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Everywhere in the examples is shown to invoke the delete method from firebase_tools, but anywhere it isn't imported. Maybe this is one of the issues, but I cannot fix it. Tried many times, read almost anything similar to my problem.

The second problem is that I cannot resolve the CORS issue when I invoke the function.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-myProjectId.cloudfunctions.net/cleanupAfterVehicle' from 
origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request 
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The function is deployed successfully in the firebase according to the firebase CLI. If you need more info about the problem say it.

I would be very glad if someone helps me to get into these functions.

Best regards!

Comment: Please edit the question to narrow it down to a single issue.  Posts with multiple issues might get closed as off-topic.  I suggest dealing with CORS separately in a different post.

Answer (score 0):

This defines a **HTTP** function:

```
export const cleanupAfterVehicle = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 }).https.onRequest(async
```

That is **not** the same as a **Callable** function.

HTTP Functions are invoked by sending HTTP request to them, while Callable Functions are invoked by using the client-side Functions SDK. While Callable Functions are built on top of HTTP Functions under the hood, you cannot invoke regular HTTP Functions with the Callable wrapper.

So you will either have to invoke the function through a regular HTTP (`GET~ from the looks of it) request, or convert your Cloud Functions code to implement` exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall(` as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function).